# A question an estimate for eigenvalues of eigenvalue of Laplace

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

Let $(M,g)$ be a closed Riemannnian manifold with dimension $m$, $\Delta$ be the Laplace operator and $\phi_i$ be the $i$-th eigenfunction of $\Delta$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ and $\|\phi_i\|_{L^2}=1$.

My question is why the following estimate holds or how could we obtain a similar estimate:
\begin{equation}
|\phi_i|+\lambda_i^{\frac12}|\nabla\phi_i|+\lambda_i^{-1}|\nabla^2\phi_i|\leq C\lambda_i^{\frac{m-1}{4}},
\end{equation}
where $C$ is independent of $i$.

The above estimate is coming from the paper of [Hein and Song](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.02940) about Calabi-Yau conifold. It is equation (2.15) and it said this could be obtained from Moser iteration and Schauder theory. Sorry for previous incomplete question.

Comment: This question needs more context. Where did you find this estimate? What is $C$? Why do you expect it to hold?

Comment: @Kajelad Thank you for the comment and sorry for previous incomplete question. This is an inequality when I read the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.02940.pdf and it said it could be obtained by Moser iteration and Schaduer theory.

Comment: @Kajelad I first thought it is a classical result about any eigenfunction just I don't know, but your comment, I realize that it is about the i-th eigenvalue and the constant should be independent of $i$ or the eigenvalue.